# Bot wont join in "join" slash command discord.py V2.0

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to update some old code to use slash commands and in the old code I have a join command that just makes the bot join the current voice channel. I have done some research but all I could find was just older tutorials on how you did a join command with the old prefix and ctx. The solution I am seeking is a little code example on how a join command could look like without using ctx beacuse thats not in slash commands.

The code is not done yet but here is inside my music cog where the command should be:

```py
import requests
import asyncio
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from rich import print
#---
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
#---
YDL_OPTIONS = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', 
    'noplaylist': True,
    'quiet': True,
    'prostprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '256',
    }]
    }
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
    'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
    'options': '-vn'
}
#---

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name = "join", description="Boten joinar din nuvarande röst-kanal!")
    async def join(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        #bot joins voice channel cod e here
        await interaction.response.send_message("Ok")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(music(bot))
```

Comment: You removed the only part of the code that matters from your post... We can't tell you what's wrong with your join command if you don't include the join command.....

Comment: I have now updated the question, and I hope you understand now. Just tell me if i should rephrase again :)

Comment: Your old code would work just fine. It's the same thing with interactions as with message commands, you don't have to do anything special. Joining a voice channel is not related to message commands or interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It as pretty much the same for slash commands as compared to normal command, you use the`interaction` object instead of `ctx`.

```
@app_commands.command()
    async def join(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
```